# Extracting relevant content from a blob

Tags: r, parsing, blob, stringr

Daily, we get a 15+M xml dump that contains a bunch of superfluous content that masks the needed details. It is not problem to extract the content from the xml tags, however, the blob has proven to be a problem.

I can extract the headers of the info that I am after using str_extrac, however, I also need to the character vector that follows. An example

```
\n\nSubject:\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-21-1390067357-1580818891-1801674531-43388\n
```

Unfortunately, I cannot post a full copy of the blob, as it contains proprietary content. As you can see, the fields that I need are all separated with embedded new line and tab characters, which I am trying to trigger on, but I cannot find a way to configure str_extract to capture the additional content.

Any insight you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Blobs usually have binary/raw data, and that doesn't look like it does, so does `strsplit("\n\nSubject:\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-21-1390067357-1580818891-1801674531-43388\n", "[\n\t]+")` work?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is only a small sample of the entire blob. The leading characters are of variable length. I tried the strsplit(MT, "Security ID:) which works. I next tried a strsplit on the next event in the string that I want to capture, and I get a error calling out non-character argument. There are embedded new line and tab, but I do not think that should be causing the error.

Comment: The desired output:  Security ID:   S-1-5-21-1390067357-1580818891-1801674531-43388

Comment: @Bill, is this general enough? `gsub(pattern = ".*\t|\nSecurity ID:\t|\n([0-9A-Z-]*)", replacement = "\\1", string)`

Comment: Skaqqs, looks like where I have been working towards. Thank you very much!